# How to write event buffer for Java Swing MouseEvent?

Tags: java, swing, events, buffer, mouseevent

I have been trying to find a solution to this question for a while. What is the best practice for writing a swing event buffer? The idea is when triggering an action from a mouse gesture, such as 'mouseMoved', as the events may be fired many times, I only want to trigger the last call - for example,

if the mouse was clicked five times, while the first click listener is being executed, and four are queued, the next call will be the fifth one - all previous ones will be skipped.

It seems that I should be using the [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#remove%28java.lang.Runnable%29) class, as it can remove unsubmitted tasks, but I am still not quite sure. All help is appreciated!

Comment: If you are getting all these events queued up you should consider using SwingWorkers to delegate your long jobs to

Answer (score 2):

user1291492 is right, this shouldn't happen at all. You should *never* run any code that could take longer than a couple of milliseconds to complete in an event handler. The [SwingWorker documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) contains examples and explanations on how to do it. The most important quotes is

> Time-consuming tasks should not be run on the Event Dispatch Thread. Otherwise the application becomes unresponsive.

To address the original question, there are two patterns I usually employ:

1. Use flags to mark actions that should be executed at some point in the future. When there's no other work for some time I check all the flags, reset them and perform the appropriate actions.
2. When scheduling work for a worker thread, hold a reference to it. Every time before scheduling new work, cancel the previously scheduled work. Most often used with CancellationTokens in C#/Async.

Comment: Thank you! I was using SwingWorker actually, I was looking for a good way to cancel background tasks. I will give it a try. Many thanks!